# How do you remove unicode characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to remove some unicode characters[E000-F8FF] from a string.How do I go about doing this in javascript? 
For example I looking to strip E018 from this string :

The IT Crowd 

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/[\uE000-\uF8FF]/g, '');
```

Screenshot taken from firebug:

[image]

Comment: hi mate thanks of ryour answer,but its not working as I expected.Are you able replace this string "The IT Crowd  " with your code?

Comment: this is awesome. How would I remove the full Unicode range?